# how to customise the specific subclasses which are extending the common abstract class

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

I have an base abstract class containing common methods to which there are subclasses which are extending that abstract class in its own specific way.

Now please advise is there any other way in object oriented methodology in which say lets say if i wanted to implement any specific functionality for all subclasses but i do not want to declare it in abstract class also , can i implement that specif functionality in subclass itself but I am confused will it be a god design ie there any specif pattern in which i can modify all the subclass without disturbing the parent class

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking. I started hyperventilating while reading the question

Comment: I am not able to get your concern. What you want to achieve? Every child class can have its own implementation and methods.

Comment: There's no rule that forbids a child class from implementing a method its parent did not provide for, and there's not rule that forbids all child classes of the same parent from implementing the same method that the parent did not provide for.   What you give up, if the parent did not provide for it, is the ability for clients of this hierarchy to invoke this method common to all children without knowing what kind of child they actually have - treating them all as if they were instances of the parent class won't give the client access to that method, even though all clients really do have it.

Comment: Please add some code to clarify the context of your question.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to implement any specific functionality for all subclasses, Then it is good to have it in the abstract class itself otherwise it leads to code duplication.

Is there any specific reason you don't want to implement the method in abstract class.